# Can you execute a collection which reads a parameterize body from file which also uses a data file?

Tags: postman, newman

I am trying to run newman cli and specifying a collection where the body is read from file as below

```
"body": {
  "mode": "file",
  "file": {
    "src": "body.json"
  }
}
```

and passing a CSV data file but for some reason newman is not replacing the parameterised body with the data from the CSV.

I have a json file containing the body of my request

```
{
  "name": "{{name}}
}
```

and a CSV file containing the following

```
name
Pete
Joe
```

So my body is parameterised stored in a file and I am want to use a data file to populate the requests in the running which will execute 2 runner with the values in my CVS file.

Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that other parts of the collection file are correct the `body` should be like below:

```
"body": {
    "mode": "formdata",
    "formdata": [
        {
            "key": "file",
            "type": "file",
            "src": "body.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `body.json` file should live in the same directory that the collection exist. otherwise full path is required

This is basically the JSON representation of what you in the Postman UI. You can provide any `key` you'd like but type should be `file`

[image]

You can provide any `key` you'd like but type should be `file`

Comment: By specifying formdata type file the api call will be uploading a file. That is not what I want to achieve. I have my raw body defined in a file which is templated and I want to use a data file to populate the variables in my body file

Comment: In that case you probably need to use global or environment variables depending on the nature of your request and collection. Could you give more details on the request you want to build in collection runner?

Comment: I have a json file containing the body of my request
`
{
  "name": "{{name}}
}
`
and a CSV file containing the following
`
name
Pete
Joe
`
So my body is parameterised stored in a file and I am want to use a data file to populate the requests in the running which will execute 2 runner with the values in my CVS file.